# Spring Boot- ZUUL and request throttling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have couple of question on API-Gateway and request throttling

- Do we have any inbuilt feature in zuul/ribbon to throttle request?
  if not
- Does spring provide any feature?
- I can use Guava rate limiter to throttle requests or bucket pattern.

Comment: The answer is no for #1 and #2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit` module.
https://github.com/marcosbarbero/spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a PRE route filter in zuul in which you can implement your own throttling algorithm or use something like
https://github.com/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j which is java rate limiting library based on token-bucket algorithm

Answer (score 0):

spring boot zuul rate limit

Please check this.